# Datatable serverSide processing with fake json data service

Tags: angular, datatables

In my angular application, I am using datatable which is having following options.

```
options = {
    sDom: 'rt<"bottom"p>',
    pagingType: 'full_numbers',
    ajax: (data, callback, settings) => {
      this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
        .subscribe((response : any) => {
          callback({
            data:response
          });
        })
    },
    columns: [
      { data: "userId" },
      { data: "id" },
      { data: "title" },
      { data: "body" }
    ]
  };
```

which returns me a paginated table with 10 rows per page. What I want is `serverSide` processing with this options. When I have appended `serverSide: true`, `processing: true` within the options. I got the table having pagination but none of use. All the results were displayed in single page. I don't have much clarity about callback in the ajax call and I have also gone through official [example](https://datatables.net/examples/server_side/simple.html) of `serverSide` processing provided in Datatable site but it didn't work for me. Need help.

Answer (score 0):

I am using jquery not angular but i hope this will help you.

```
$('#tblAccounts').DataTable({
                "dom": "<'row'<'col-md-6 col-sm-12'l><'col-md-6 col-sm-12'f>r>t<'row'<'col-md-5 col-sm-12'i><'col-md-7 col-sm-12'p>>",
                "paging": true,
                "info": true,
                "ordering": true,
                "search": true,
                "processing": true,
                "serverSide": true,
                "destroy": true,
                "ajax": {
                    "url": "/Home/LoadList",
                    "type": "POST",
                    "data": function (d) {
                        d.startDate = $("#txtStartDate").val();
                        d.endDate = $("#txtEndDate").val();
                        d.head = $("#drpAccountHeads").val();
                    }
                },
                "columns": [
                    { "data": name, "title": "Name", "className": "", "orderable": false, "searchable": false },
                    { "data": plot, "title": "Plot", "className": "", "orderable": false, "searchable": false },
                    { "data": no, "title": "No", "className": "", "orderable": false, "searchable": false }
                ],
                "order": [[0, "asc"]],

                "initComplete": function (settings, json) {

                }
            });
```